# Concerning the code for insertion sort

Tags: algorithm, insertion-sort

I am currently reading Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen and co. I have some trouble deducing the pseudo-code for it. I understand what the algorithm does intuitively and how certain elements are sorted in a array of integers.
For instance **array = [5][2][4][6][1][3]**, the key is **j=2**, and **i = j-1**. It then checks is **i > 0** and **[5]** then swaps **[2]** with **[5]**. Here comes the confusing part: **i = i -1**?? I mean we just set **i = j-1**, and why are we decreamenting **i** again?

Here is the following pseudo-code:

```
for j = 2 to A.length
    key = A[j]
    i = j - 1
    while i > 0 and A[i] > key
          A[i + 1] = A[i]
          i = i - 1         //this the part I do not understand.
    A[i + 1] = key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insertion outlined here does the following:

At each j, the part of the array before index j is sorted and after index j is not sorted.

So the insertion sort finds a suitable place for the new A[j] and inserts it there.

For example, at `j = 4` and `i = 3` if the array is

```
2 4 5 3 1 0  
      ^

The array before element 3 is sorted.  
1. So it checks that 3 is less than 5, hence copies 5 to array[i+1] (i+1 = 4).  
   2 4 5 5 1 0  
2. Then it decrements i checks that 3 is less than 4, hence copies 4 to array[i+1] (i+1 = 3).  
   2 4 4 5 1 0   
3. Then it checks that 3 is more than 2, hence stops and makes A[i+1] = key.  
   2 3 4 5 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The array elements `1..(j-1)` are already sorted and you try to insert the element `a[j]` into the sorted elements. This is done by the while loop. Starting with element `a[j-1]` the new element `a[j]` is compared with the already sorted elements one by one until the proper insertion place is found. As long as `a[i]` is larger, `a[j]` must go before that element so we move up `a[i]` by one place and reduce `i` in order to come to the next element to compare.

To understand the algorithm, I suggest you make a desk check with a small example. Follow all the steps and see how it behaves.

Comment: Thank you for the advice with trying to make an example. I did that and following the steps and made sense of it :)